# javascripts and CSS (404 not found) on WAS8

Tags: javascript, css, websphere

We are upgrading from WAS6.1 to WAS8.iN One of our test environments they created and instance of WAS8.Took ear file of the web app from WAS6.1 and deployed to WAS8.The web app is up running on WAS8. However, the javascripts and CSS are not loading(404 NOT FOUND) there. No changes were done to the app to specifically run on WAS8.I am looking for ideas on what the problem can be. Is it permissions ? is it because the the WAS6.1 EAR file was deployed to WAS8 ?In Chrome debugger when I look at the sources it initially shows the javascripts and CSS folders even though the files appear to be empty. However, when I navigate to the next screen in the app the javascript and CSS folders in the Chrome debugger sources no longer show at all

Thank you for any ideas and help with this.

Comment: Can you check, if these resources are actually in ear file (maybe you've served these files from http server not WAS)? Also check ibm-web-ext.xmi file if fileServingEnabled is enabled (true).

Comment: Thank you Gas for looking into this. Yes,CSS and javascripts both in ear file on WAS8.Also,fileServingEnabled is enabled (true) in ibm-web-ext.xmi file.I wonder, if the issue is that my WAS8 ear file was built for WAS6.1 using JDK1.5

Comment: Are you accessing the app directly or via IHS? Is your ear unchanged from 6.1 (J2EE 1.4)  or you migrated descriptors to JEE6?